# How in pandas we can convert from one form to another?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following scenario in python with Pandas, below is for just an example
in fact the real dataframe returns 15k objects for projects and another 15k objects for products

```
#cur is a connector to snowflake instance
rows = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall(), columns=['product', 'project'])
json_data = rows.to_dict(orient='dict')
print('projects_products =', json_data)
projects_products = {
    "project": {
    '0': 'project0',
    '1': 'project0',
    '2': 'project1',
    '3': 'project1',
    '4': 'project2',
    '5': 'project2',
    },
    "product":{
    '0': 'product1',
    '1': 'product2',
    '2': 'product3',
    '3': 'product4',
    '4': 'product5',
    '5': 'product6',
    }
}
```

How in pandas I can convert these data from above format to below?

```
merged_list = [ 
    { "key": 'project0', "cat": 'product1' },
    { "key": 'project0', "cat": 'product2' },
    { "key": 'project1', "cat": 'product3' },
    { "key": 'project1', "cat": 'product4' },
    { "key": 'project2', "cat": 'product5' },
    { "key": 'project2', "cat": 'product6' },
]
```

I tried going the primitive way, but it takes ages

```
projects_products = {
    "response": { 
           "product": { ... 
                },
            "project": { ...
                }
    }
}
def convert_dict():
    projects_list = []
    for project in projects_products['response']['project']:
        for product in projects_products['response']['product']:
            if projects_products['response']['project'][project] == projects_products['response']['project'][product]:
                projects_list.append({ "key": projects_products['response']['product'][product], "cat": projects_products['response']['project'][project] })
    return projects_list
start = timeit.default_timer()
convert_dict()
end = timeit.default_timer()
print(end-start)
```

The conversion took 109 seconds

```
$ python3 convert.py 
109.38614280600001
```

Comment: In `merged_list` are key and cat supposed to be the numbers 0, 1, 2, ... above or just the strings "key" and "cat"?

Comment: Just the strings "key" and "cat"

Comment: The question was already answered @Simone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rename` columns before call `to_dict(orient='records')`:

```
>>> rows.rename(columns={'project': 'key', 'product': 'cat'}) \
        .to_dict(orient='records')

[{'key': 'project0', 'cat': 'product1'},
 {'key': 'project0', 'cat': 'product2'},
 {'key': 'project1', 'cat': 'product3'},
 {'key': 'project1', 'cat': 'product4'},
 {'key': 'project2', 'cat': 'product5'},
 {'key': 'project2', 'cat': 'product6'}]
```

For 15k rows, the conversion took:

```
>>> len(rows)
15000

>>> %timeit rows.rename(columns={'project': 'key', 'product': 'cat'}).to_dict(orient='records')
23.5 ms ± 123 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Yes, I marked your answer as the solution.